# Swift: unresolved identifier from a switch statement

Tags: xcode, scope, swift, switch-statement, closures

I'm trying the following in the playground in Xcode6-Beta4, following the apple's [swift tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html):

```
let vegetable = "red pepper"
switch vegetable{
case "celery":
    let vegetableComment = "Add some raisins and make ants on a log."
case "cucumber", "watercress":
    let vegetableComment = "That would make a good tea sandwich."
case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    let vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)"
default:
    let vegetableComment = "Everything tastes good in soup."
}
```

then I try to call the variable `vegetableComment` defined inside the switch statement, I got an error of `Use of unresolved identifier 'vegetableComment'`

Is it something relating the the scope / closure of switch statement in swift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it something relating the the scope / closure of switch statement in swift?

Yes, it is related to the scope of variables. You have four constants called `vegetableComment`. Each one is scoped to its `case` of the `switch` statement.

In order to access a variable that you assign inside a `switch`, you need to declare it as a `var` before entering the switch:

```
var vegetableComment = String()
let vegetable = "red pepper"
switch vegetable{
case "celery":
    vegetableComment = "Add some raisins and make ants on a log."
case "cucumber", "watercress":
    vegetableComment = "That would make a good tea sandwich."
case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)"
default:
    vegetableComment = "Everything tastes good in soup."
}
```

Comment: You have just a problem as soon as you fill it with different types. (string, integer, dictionary)